# How to make HTML table with 2 column merge and 2 row merge?

Tags: html-table, row, multiple-columns

I need A & B Colum to merge, also 1 & a row marge. Here I use colspan for merge A & B, also use rowspan for 1 & a row merge. But the Result not match my needs. I need look like this image
[Demo Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GACou.png)

```css
table, th, td {
 border: 1px solid black;
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
 padding: 5px;
 text-align: left;    
}
```

```html
<table>
 <tr>
   <td colspan="2">A</td>
   <td colspan="2">B</td>
   <td>C</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td rowspan="2">1</td>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td rowspan="2">a</td>
   <td>b</td>
   <td>c</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think solved the issue you mentioned. you may try it. I hope you'll satisfy with the solution.
Thank you.

```css
table, th, td {
 border: 1px solid black;
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
 padding: 5px;
 text-align: left;    
}
```

```html
<table>
 
 <tr>
   <td colspan="2">A</td>
   <td>C</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td rowspan="2">1</td>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>a</td>
   <td>b</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```